# How to do apache redirect from 'any' incoming domain to the main domain

Tags: apache, redirect

Some 3rd party web site domain `www.example.com` was pointed to an IP address of our web site - `www.oursite.com`. So basically, accessing `example.com` opens up `oursite.com` (but with `example.com` visible in the browser)

I was playing around with Apache redirection but I can't manage to make it work. First I tried redirection for given `example.com` address. Then I looked for a way to redirect from any incoming domain. No luck in both scenarios. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/*(.*)$ http://www.example.com/$1 [R=301,NC]
```

Will redirect all requests that are not for "www.example.com", to "www.example.com".